# Do I need to use Apache Kafka alongside another DBMS in my use case?

Tags: database, rdbms, apache-kafka

I have a project that relies on getting data from IoT devices.

then I display the data analytics using a graph (in real-time) and also the state of the machines (are they working or not and the reason for stopping ... etc).

something like https://evocon.com/
The important thing is that I decided to use Apache Kafka because I found that it really fits my use case perfectly.

Do I use Apache Kafka just for data coming from IoT devices alongside another DBMS for other storage like (users, factories,...etc)? or I will just use Apache Kafka?

Because from what I have read, some say that it can be used as a replacement for other DBMS depending on your requirements but I'm really confused here. I opt for using another DBMS here, however, I decided to ask for your opinions.

This is a final-study project so it's really important for me and I'm responsible for deciding the technology and architecture to use.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: List down the features of Kafka and your DBMS side by side and validate it with your application requirements.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have to see the exact claims that Kafka can replace an RDBMS but from experience, I would say don't try to use a messaging system as a database and don't try use a database as a messaging system.

These tools serve different purposes.  It's like trying to bang in nails with a screwdriver.  You might be able to do it but it's going to be a lot more difficult and more error-prone.

If you need to cut corners, you'll be better off using the RDBMS as a makeshift messaging system unless you have very high volumes of messages.

Comment: this is the conclusion that I came to at the end, if it could replace an RDBMS then there is no longer a need for them. "If you need to cut corners, you'll be better off using the RDBMS as a makeshift messaging system unless you have very high volumes of messages.", I will have a high volumes of messages because the number of machines will grow.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might not need a full RDBMS.  I think Kafka still requires Zoookeeper which is basically a hierarchical key-value store.  If you just need to manage simple configuration, for example, you might just want to use that instead of an RDBMS.  RDBMS is a very general solution so it's crucial to know exactly what your requirement is to be able to say whether another solution can be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think my configurations are not that simple, as an example in the user table there's a hierarchy(administrator, maintenance manager, production manager, production operator, etc), and also I need to keep track of who created who?  I think I will just go with an RDBMS.

Comment: @AimadQuouninich As I noted ZK is a hierarchical datastore, that's it's natural use case.  You can also build a hierarchy in a RDBMs but it's a modelling exercise.  You should probably just go with what you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

We used kafka as our storage layer for many years. It's simple and reliable and is very similar to the replicated commit log component of many databases. We just read the log into memory on startup and did all our queries directly from memory.

If your queries fit the model, you can take advantage of [kafka streams](https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/). This works really well for dashboard-style queries, where you want to constantly display a running total of some incoming data, or the last n events, or things like that.

If your queries are more user-driven and freeform, and your data is large enough, you'll probably want to add a database of some sort. We finally got to the scale where we feel that is necessary, and it's no small task.

Comment: This seems like an anti pattern. There's a reason why Kafka's default data retention period is 7 days, it's to make the fact that Kafka's meant to be used as a temporary store as obvious as possible. Because by default it deletes your messages after a week. No ordinary database does that, because databases are meant to hold data, indefinitely. I am not saying you couldn't have made it work, obviously you did, I am just saying it seems like a misuse of the technology whose original purpose is something else.

Comment: "If your queries fit the model, you can take advantage of kafka streams. This works really well for dashboard-style queries". This exactly why I'm using kafka because in the dashboard I need to constantly display analytics and the status of the machines

Comment: @andy, I agree it can be an anti-pattern if applied in the wrong circumstances, but it's also a use case that Kafka was intentionally designed for, and has some nice advantages. See [It's Okay To Store Data in Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/okay-store-data-apache-kafka/).

Comment: I've seen data get lost with Kafka.  If you don't configure it exactly right, it will hard delete your data, no questions asked.  One of the things I've also learned about Kafka is that the people who built it might be a little overconfident.  I've spent a fair amount of time digging through their code trying to figure out why we keep getting random failures and it was not very comforting.